# Can I have my UITableView detect and respond to a swipe jesture?

Tags: uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0, swipe

I don't want the swipe to delete the row but do something else.
What code do I need to add to the UITableViewController to have that happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at the docs, you might be able to code around the default behavior by not enabling the swipe to delete stuff, and looking at the example code mentioned in the UISwipeGestureRecognizer class.

I don't know what you application is, but one thing I feel compelled to mention is that it'd be considered a design flaw to have an editable list where swipe didn't do the delete behavior. This would break the principle of least astonishment, and confuse users.

That said, you might have a great use, I don't know. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My list is not editable, but you may be right, still considering it

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` in your `viewDidLoad`. For example a right swipe gesture can be implemented like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // more stuff

    // Recognizing right swiping gestures
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipe:)];
    // right swipe direction is default
    rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeGestureRecognizer];
    [rightSwipeGestureRecognizer release];
}

- (void)rightSwipe:(id)sender
{
    // Do something
}
```

As always, more information available in [Apple's most excellent documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).